# What are the conditions for a coordinatewise optimum to be a local optimum

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

if $x*$ is a coordinatewise optimum of a function $f$, (i.e $x*$ is an optimum of $f$ in all directions), what are the conditions (on the function $f$ or $x*$) for $x*$ to be a local optimum of $f$.